# Get a specific parameter out of HTML

Tags: html, vb.net

I want to check my online wallet for new transactions from this site 
[instawallet.org](http://instawallet.org).
How can I get the value where the 0 BTC is placed and set it as variable?

Here is my code which doesn't work:

```
  Dim WebClient As New WebClient()
    Dim Btc As String = WebClient.DownloadString(Mywallet-generate one of your own by going to instawallet.org)
    Btc = Split(Btc, "<span class='digits' title='")(1).Split("</span>")(0).Split(">")(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for the below tag

```
<div id="balance">
```

The reason for this is that the

```
<span>
```

tag does not contain an ID property, yet is encompassed within the

```
<div id="balance">
```

tag.

Try to download/find/extract the DIV tag with the id of "balance" and that will contain the span tag with the actual balance.